# Find an infinite sequence of numbers that can't be the derivatives of power series

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

[image]

First, I noticed that the nth derivative of $f$ at $0$ is $n!\cdot a_n$, but this does not really help me to construct a sequence of numbers that can not be generated by the sequence ${f(0),f'（0），f''(0),\ldots}$.  How should I construct the sequence?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff You need slightly more: $f(z) = 1/(1-z)$ has $f^{(n)}(0) = n!$.

Comment: I was thinking $\sum a_n x^n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a sequence that grows fast enough to make the radius of convergence of
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!} z^n
$$
less than $1$.